# Select DISTINCT dates with hour segmentation

Tags: postgresql, group-by

I have a table with counters from a machine. 
timestamp, input, ouput.

I need to get the input and output which happened at the start and end of a session. 
A session is a different day BUT it starts at 6:00 a.m and ends at 6 a.m next day. 
I use to do DISTINCT(DATE(timestamp)) to get the different days, BUT it does not cover the part wich happens next day AND covers the previous day data till 6:00 am.

How can I group by "sessions"?

Comment: i'll clarify the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shift the time for grouping purposes:

```
DISTINCT(DATE(timestamp - INTERVAL '6' HOUR))
```